# Почему не виден текст в QGraphicsView? (PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene

Разбираюсь с графической сценой PyQt5. Почему текст не отображается?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(600,600)

        sq = QRectF(100,100,100,100)
        obj = QGraphicsScene(sq)

        obj.addText("Привет", font = QFont("8pt MS Reference Sans Serif"))
        obj2 = QGraphicsView(self)
        obj2.setScene(obj)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в координатах, которые вы неправильно указали:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 600)
        ####################################
        obj = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 100, 100)
        ####################################
        obj.addText("Привет", font=QFont("8pt MS Reference Sans Serif"))
        obj2 = QGraphicsView(self)
        obj2.setScene(obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```